# How to print only last sum output of python

Tags: python, printing, sum, iteration, break

I need to print only the last result of my Python execution line.

The assignment is to produce a for loop that iterates the squares of 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 and sums them (255). I need to set the end of my range to 100 and break at 9 in order to stop execution.

So far I have

```
i = 0
mySum = 0
for i in range(5,100):
  mySum += (i**2)
  if i > 9:
     break
  print(mySum)
```

which prints

```
25
61
110
174
255
```

So for some reason, while I understand that it's squaring the ints, then adding them to the previous results 5 times over, it's not  something I need to show.
What do I change to remove all but the last result (255)?

Comment: Simply, print it outside the loop

Comment: Just unindent the `print(mySum)` to move it outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: You can also remove the `i = 0` at the start of the code since you never use that value outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way it should work.

```
mySum = 0
for i in range(5,100):
    mySum += (i**2)
    if i > 9:
        break
print(mySum)
```

Otherwise you can do:

```
mySum = 0
for i in range(5,100):
    mySum += (i**2)
    if i > 9:
        print(mySum)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

mySum = 0

for i in range(5,100):

```
mySum += (i**2)

if i == 9:

    break
```

print(mySum)

This ended up working and posting a single 255, apparently, the bigger issue was the i>9 when it should have been i==9 to stop the executions. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear console after each iteration by using:

```
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('clear')

i = 0
mySum = 0
for i in range(5,100):
 mySum += (i**2)
 if i > 9:
    break
 clear()
 print(mySum)
```